# Получение отправленных заголовков и ответа от сервера - curl

Tags: php, curl

Метод `sendQuery` post-запрос с заданными заголовками и данными.
Этот метод используется по всему проекту. Иногда во время разработки происходят какие-то ошибки, которые возвращает сервер на post-запрос.

Возникла потребность в логах. Каким образом модно доработать метод, что бы при в некий файл записывал все что отправил серверу, и все что получил? (именно все заголовки, вместе с теми, что добавляет сам curl и полностью весь ответ от сервера, там 200 ОК и т.п.)

```
    private static function sendQuery($headers, $query) {
        if(is_array($headers) && is_array($query)) {
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, SERVICE_URL);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($query));
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $result = curl_exec($curl);
            curl_close($curl);
            return json_decode($result);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: [`CURLOPT_VERBOSE` + `CURLOPT_STDERR`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4406238/4279) — если это подходит для вашего случая, то опубликуйте как ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Перегонять заголовки и запрос в JSON и писать его в файл

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]